# 1 [main] 972 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION explanation and how to fix

Tags: c++, function, object, pointers

To ask as simply as possible can anyone explain why this code:

```
LinkedListByGrade::LinkedListByGrade(vector<Node> myNodes) {
int lowestGradeFound = myNodes[0].getGrade();
Node *pFristNode = new Node();
cout << "New node created" << endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i <= myNodes.size(); i++) {
    if (myNodes[i].getGrade() < lowestGradeFound) {

        cout << "if triggered" << endl;
        lowestGradeFound = myNodes[i].getGrade();
        pFristNode->reassasignNode(myNodes[i].getFristName(),
                myNodes[i].getLastName(), myNodes[i].getId(),
                myNodes[i].getGrade());
        cout << "int reassassigned" << endl;
    }
```

Is giving me this error:

```
1 [main] Project 972 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION 
2130 [main] Project 972 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to Project.exe.stackdump
```

and ideas on how to fix it?

(Sorry I left in the diagnostic print statements.)

Also this is the only code that affects myNodes:

```
vector<Node> Students;
Node node1("Bobby", "zilch",28,55);
Node node2("Evil", "Dentist",308,55);
Node node3("Raz", "Buton",10,55);
Students.push_back(node1);
Students.push_back(node2);
Students.push_back(node3);

cout<<"stuff"<<endl;
 LinkedListByGrade myList = LinkedListByGrade(Students);
```

Comment: Is `myNodes.size() == 0` when `int lowestGradeFound = myNodes[0].getGrade();` is invoked? You're going to have to run this in a debugger. StackOverflow can't do that for you!

Comment: You need to learn to use the debugger. We can't tell what `myNodes` contains when this code executes; you're the only one who can determine that and step through the code to figure out the problem.

Comment: ok but based on what you are saying it should be something to do with the vector being off?

Comment: We're saying we can't tell you that - **you** are the only one who can tell. *Use the debugger.* Set a breakpoint on the start of the `for` loop, run the code, and step through it to figure out what's causing the access violation. We *can not* do that for you. (That's the third reference we've made to **the debugger**. Have you gotten the hint yet that you need to **use the debugger**?)

Comment: @Nood - You have one problem here `for (size_t i = 0; i <= myNodes.size(); i++)`. If `size()` is 3, you will try to access elements 0, 1, 2, and 3, which is one too many.

Comment: @BoPersson Thank you. You have know Idea how long that's been throwing me off. And such a stupid mistake too. Not having a great day I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say that for sure, but you're accessing memory that is not allocated to you, so it's likely you're running over the boundary of `myNodes`. **You** will be able to determine this *by using your debugger*.

What I can say for sure is that in the first line of your function you call:

```
int lowestGradeFound = myNodes[0].getGrade();
```

If there are no items in `myNodes`, then this should cause an access violation.

And you're certainly running over the end of `myNodes` in your `for`-loop because you're accessing `myNodes[myNodes.size()]`.

Try something like this:

```
LinkedListByGrade::LinkedListByGrade(vector<Node> const& myNodes) {
    // Pass by const-reference! ------------------^

    // Set this to something high. Don't access the vector, in case there are no
    // elements therein:
    int lowestGradeFound = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    // Where is this deleted?
    Node *pFirstNode = new Node();

    // Use iterators, not indices for looping over a container...
    for (vector<Node>::iterator i = myNodes.begin(), end = myNodes.end(); != end; ++i)
    {
        // Access element by `i->`
        if (i->getGrade() < lowestGradeFound)
        {
            // Now you can assign this safely...
            lowestGradeFound = i->getGrade();
            pFirstNode->reassasignNode(
                i->getFirstName(),
                i->getLastName(),
                i->getId(),
                i->getGrade());
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

But you really, *really* need to learn to use your debugger!

Comment: The reason I didn't use the debugger is because it gives me an error. I have done much research on it yet but I need to work on my code more then the debugger. Here is the error if you have an answer for it `Can't find a source file at "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/iostream" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.`

Comment: You won't need 'iostream' to debug this function!